# Gradle / SonarQube documentation issue with custom source sets

Tags: gradle, sonarqube, sonarqube-scan

The specific problem I'm trying to solve is that integration tests are not showing up on the server.

Also the example code given here appears to be wrong:
[SonarQube: Analyzing Custom Source Sets](http://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SCAN/Analyzing+with+SonarQube+Scanner+for+Gradle)

Specifically this code example:

```
sonarqube {
    properties {
        properties["sonar.sources"] += sourceSets.custom.allSource.srcDirs
        properties["sonar.tests"] += sourceSets.integTest.allSource.srcDirs
    }
}
```

Running with this results in:

```
Invalid value of sonar.tests for...
```

What should this actually be? Based on another forum I was reading, this is supposed to be a list of comma separated directories. So I tried:

```
sonarqube {
  properties {
    properties["sonar.tests"] += sourceSets.integrationTest
                                                 .allSource.srcDirs.join(",")
  }
}
```

...same error. Note that `ingegrationTest` is correct for our build.

Comment: Can you try properties["sonar.tests"] += "," + sourceSets.integrationTest
                                                 .allSource.srcDirs.join(",")

Comment: Tried this. I got the same result.

Comment: properties { properties["sonar.tests"]... } seems really odd. Shouldn't it be something like properties {property["sonar.tests"]...} ??

Comment: I have tested and everything works fine. Could you please provide the rest of the error message after "Invalid value of sonar.tests for...". You may have to filter non existing folders, and be sure to not provide duplicates.

Comment: @JulienH.-SonarSourceTeam Yesterday afternoon I was able to get in some test code that should be enlightening today. Will post it when I have it.

Comment: Question: I see a lot of these jacoco-overall.exec files. What, if anything should I be doing with these?

Comment: OK so sonar is finding NONE of my *.exec files, not just the jacoco-overall.exec files. I can see where they are created and then I can see "JaCoCoSensor: JaCoCo report not found", then I can prove it's there using 'ls' from CLI.

Comment: Could you please avoid to mix topics. We were talking about custom source sets and now you have added Jacoco report issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following code works :

```
sonarqube {

    properties {
        properties["sonar.tests"] += sourceSets.integrationTest.allSource.srcDirs.findAll({it.exists()})

        if (file("$project.buildDir/jacoco/test.exec").exists())
            property "sonar.jacoco.reportPath", "$project.buildDir/jacoco/test.exec"
        if (file("$project.buildDir/jacoco/integrationTest.exec").exists())
            property "sonar.jacoco.itReportPath", "$project.buildDir/jacoco/integrationTest.exec"
    }
}
```

I import this into every project that needs it to avoid using subProjects. According to the Gradle docs, using subProjects and / or allProjects causes coupling which negatively impacts parallelism. IDK if importing is better but I hope so.

Comment: Try something like: `properties["sonar.tests"] += sourceSets.integrationTest.allSource.srcDirs.findAll({it.exists()})`

Comment: NullPointerException if done outside the properties block. Trying inside now.

Comment: This works but I find it confusing to use properties["some.property"] INSIDE a properties block. It's still better than what I've got though.

Comment: @JulienH.-SonarSourceTeam Do you want the cheese points or should I just update the answer?